# "Add Account" is not letting me create a new Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

I am trying to add a third email account to my google ID. It won't let me. It just takes me in circles.

1. From the dropdown menu under my name icon, I select: Add Account
2. That takes me to a new tab or window, with a two-step login (usename, password)
3. Once I login it takes me to whichever account I logged into. There is no option to complete what I started.

To me that is not logical as it does not do as suggested by the menu item selected (add account).

Answer (score 2):

"Add Account" is a bit of a misnomer, I agree.  As you suspected, though, it's only to add an account to the list of those that are already logged in.

The quickest way to get a new account is to open an incognito/private browsing window and go to https://accounts.google.com, click on "More Options" and then "Create Account."  Otherwise, it's going to keep asking you to log in to one of your existing accounts.

[image]

Then, you can use the Add Account button in the main window to log in to your new account and add it to the list.